# How to add all notes to the localStorage so that they are saved when the page is reloaded (in the upper left corner)

Tags: javascript, html, css

JavaScript

The program can save and edit notes, but when you restart the page all recorded notes are lost.

The problem is how to leave all notes saved through the localStorage

Simple application to save notes:

```js
var ready = (callback) => {
  if (document.readyState != "loading") callback();
  else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback);
}
ready(() => { 
  var noteCount = 0;
  var activeNote = null;
document.querySelector('#btn-save').addEventListener("click", () => {
    var title = document.getElementById('title-field').value;
    var body = document.getElementById('body-field').value;
    if (title === '' && body === '') {
      alert ('Please add a title or body to your note.');
      return;
    }
    var created = new Date();
    var color = document.querySelector("notepad");
    color.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    var id = noteCount + 1;
    if (activeNote) {
        
       const note = document.getElementById(activeNote)
  note.children[0].innerHTML = title;
  note.children[1].innerHTML = created.toLocaleString("en-US");
  note.children[2].innerHTML = body;
  note.style.backgroundColor = color;
  activeNote = null;
        var box = document.querySelector('#edit-mode');
        box.classList.remove('display');
        box.classList.add("no-display");
        
    } else {
      var created = new Date();
       const listed = document.getElementById("listed");
        listed.innerHTML = listed.innerHTML + '<div id="note' + id  + '"><div class="list-title">' + title + '</div> <div class="list-date">' + created.toLocaleString("en-US") + '</div> <div class="list-text">' + body + '</div> </div>';
      noteCount++;
    };
   
     document.getElementById('title-field').value = ''
      document.getElementById('body-field').value = ''
  });
   
 
document.querySelector('#btn-delete').addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (activeNote) {
      let note = document.getElementById(activeNote);
  note.parentElement.removeChild(note);
      activeNote = null;
      var box_2 = document.querySelector('#edit-mode');
        box_2.classList.remove('display');
        box_2.classList.add("no-display");
    }
    document.getElementById('title-field').value = ''
      document.getElementById('body-field').value = ''
     
 
  });
 
 
    document.querySelector('#listed').addEventListener("click", (e) => { 
    var id = e.target.parentElement.id;
    var color = e.target.parentElement.style.backgroundColor;
    activeNote = id;
    var box_1 = document.querySelector('#edit-mode');
        box_1.classList.remove('display');
        box_1.classList.add("no-display");
    var titleSel = document.querySelectorAll('#' + id)[0].children[0].innerHTML;
    var bodySel = document.querySelectorAll('#' + id)[0].children[2].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('title-field').value = titleSel;
    document.getElementById('body-field').value = bodySel;;
    
  })

    
});
```

```css
header {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 28px;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #DEDEDE;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row-reverse;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

.headers {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#list-head {
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  width: 30.5%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

#note-head {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

noteList {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  width: 30.5%;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: solid 3px #929292;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #DEDEDE;
}

.within-list {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.list-title {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;
}

.list-date {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

.list-text {
  padding: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}

notePad {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 3px black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 60%;
  margin-top: 0;
}

#note-title {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 0 0 5px 5px;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #DEDEDE;
}

#note-body {
  padding: 5px;
}

#body-field, #title-field {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  resize: none;
}

#title-field {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#body-field {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  height: 400px;
}

#color-select {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row-reverse nowrap;
  padding: 5px 10px 0 0;
}

.color-box {
  border: solid 2px #929292;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.display {
  display: visible;
}

.no-display {
  display: none;
}

button {
  margin: 5px;
  border: solid 3px grey;
  border-radius: 10%;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #DEDEDE;
}

button:hover, .color-box:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#listed:nth-child(odd):hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#btn-save {
  background-color: #2F5032;
}

#btn-delete {
  background-color: #E41A36;
}

.white {
  background-color: white;
}


.flora {
  background-color: #78F87F;
}

.aqua {
  background-color: #79FBD6;
}




.lavendar {
  background-color: #D687FC;
}
```

```html
<<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='main.css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      The Note Machine
      
    </header>
    <main>
      <div class="headers">
        <div id="list-head">
          <b>Your Notes</b> <i>(click to edit/delete)</i>
        </div>
        <div id="note-head">
          <b>Your Notepad</b>
          <span id="edit-mode" class="no-display">
            <i> (edit mode) </i>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <noteList>
        <div id='listed'>
        </div>
      </noteList>
      <notepad>
        <div id="note-title">
          <input id="title-field" type="text" placeholder="title your note">
        </div>
        <div id="note-body">
          <textarea id="body-field"></textarea>
        </div>
      </notepad>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <button id="btn-save">Save</button>
      <button id="btn-delete">Delete / Clear </button>
    </footer>
  </body>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='Code.js'></script>
</html>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/blackessej/j47Ye/3/
ANY help in the right direction greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question - but you could either do it manually or use a library like localforage (https://www.npmjs.com/package/localforage) to basically use your local storage like a mini-DB and save and retrieve your notes from there. That'd make it persistent.

Answer (score 0):

**// It will store/set object with keys and store all objects in **notes** key with stringify**

```
 localStorage.setItem(
        "notes",
        JSON.stringify({
          name: "math notes",
          desc: "description",

        });// you can set number of object in same key("notes")
      );
```

// Read local storage :

```
if (localStorage.getItem("notes")) {
      const parsedata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes"));// it will return all object which has store while setting local Storage 
      name = parsedata.name;
      desc= parsedata.desc;

    }
```

Likewise you can set your localStorage as per your need and read it.

reference link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out where to put this snippet of code for the program to work properly, can you describe in more detail please

Comment: When you are saving note. You have store in local storage. When you are listing the notes then you have to read from local storage

Answer (score 0):

You can just set value in local storage and get that value whan you need
just add this code

```
localStorage.setItem("note", document.getElementById(activeNote));
```

when you need to get the note,then

```
localStorage.getItem("note)
```